# mod_rewrite specific urls only

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, navigation, url-rewriting

mod_rewrite is my worst enemy and cant for the life of me figure out whats going wrong, so scrapped any htaccess content i had in hope you clever fools can help a dumb fool!

we only want 3 links re-written so it only effects these.

```
index.php?portfolio=print
```

into

```
portfolio/print
```

and

```
index.php?portfolio=branding
```

into

```
portfolio/branding
```

and

```
index.php?portfolio=illustration]
```

into

```
portfolio/illustration
```

however i dont want it to effect links such as index.php?portfolio=photography.

so ideally i guess 3 lines with 3 rules that re-write only those links, the base dir is /new/.

hope ya guys can help :)

thanks again!

Owen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(print|branding|illustration)$ index.php?portfolio=$1 [L]
```

This will match what you describe using one rule with ***2 assumptions*** - no trailing slash or query string parameters.

Comment back if you expect either in the URLs. You can add another section very easily by appending it to the capture.